# Fastest solution to Testdome excercise about repeating playlist

Tags: c++, repeat, playlist

I tried to an exercise on TestDome about discovering if a playlist has repetitions ( [TestDome C++ Playlist](https://www.testdome.com/questions/cpp/playlist/18029) )

I tried to solve in this way:

```
bool isRepeatingPlaylist()
{
   std::map<std::string, int> songs;
   Song* pSong = this;
    
   while (pSong != nullptr) {
       
     if (songs[pSong->name] > 0)
         return true;
       
     songs[pSong->name]++;
     
     pSong = pSong->nextSong;

   }
     
   return false;
}
```

The feedback is that I passed 3 out of 4 test cases. The test case I'm not passing is the one about performances. Can you help me improving?

Comment: it is very confusing that you mix `int` with `bool` with integer literals

Comment: Did you try adding `this` to the map of songs too?

Comment: @Quimby thats the first iteration

Comment: @idclev463035818 Oh ,right, you are right.

Comment: Changed map to unordered_map and now I'm passing also the performance test.

Answer (score 3):

The 4th test is "Performance test on a large playlist"
when it comes to efficiency and you don't need ordered data you should use unordered_set<> or unordered_map<>.

map<> search complexity is O(log n) but it's average O(1) to O(n) in the worst case for unordered_set<> or unordered_map<>.

below code passed all 4 tests of  [TestDome C++ Playlist](https://www.testdome.com/questions/cpp/playlist/18029)

```
 bool isRepeatingPlaylist()
{

    std::unordered_set<std::string> playedSongs;
    Song *pSong = this;

    while (pSong != nullptr)
    {

        if (playedSongs.find(pSong->name) == playedSongs.end())
            playedSongs.insert(pSong->name);
        else
            return true;

        pSong = pSong->nextSong;
    }

    return false;
}
```

to use it just add #include<unordered_set>

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the standard loop detection algorithm and also gets through all the tests:

```
bool isInRepeatingPlaylist()
{
    Song *p1 = this;
    Song *p2 = this;
    do {
      p1 = p1->nextSong;
      if(p2->nextSong != nullptr) {
        p2 = p2->nextSong->nextSong;
      } else {
        break;
      }
      
      if(p1 == p2) return true;
      
    } while(p1 != nullptr && p2 != nullptr);
    
    return false;
}
```